# Using numpy.array with large number of dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

If you try to make an array with large number of dimensions in numpy, it throws an exception:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.zeros((1,) * 33)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-32dc30f6e439> in <module>()
----> 1 a = np.zeros((1,) * 33)

ValueError: sequence too large; must be smaller than 32
```

Are there any simple workarounds to this?

What are the reasons why numpy doesn't allow creating such arrays?

Comment: If you have that many dimensions, either you're going to have a ton of length-1 dimensions you could probably remove, or you're going to have trouble fitting that much array into RAM. `numpy.zeros([2]*33)` wouldn't even fit in a 32-bit address space.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, I have a lot of length-1 dimensions, and no, I can't remove them

Comment: @user2357112 Having these dimensions simplifies many operations, and (the main reason) a lot of code already relies on it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [NumPy source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.11.x/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h#L21):

```
/*
 * There are several places in the code where an array of dimensions
 * is allocated statically.  This is the size of that static
 * allocation.
 *
 * The array creation itself could have arbitrary dimensions but all
 * the places where static allocation is used would need to be changed
 * to dynamic (including inside of several structures)
 */

#define NPY_MAXDIMS 32
#define NPY_MAXARGS 32
```

You could change those defines and build from source a non-compatible version that fits your needs.