# numpy ndarray with more that 32 dimensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, python-2.x

When I try to create an numpy array with more than 32 dimensions I get an error:

```
import numpy as np

np.ndarray([1] * 33)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-78103e601d91> in <module>()
----> 1 np.ndarray([1] * 33)

ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32
```

I found this: [Using numpy.array with large number of dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192518/using-numpy-array-with-large-number-of-dimensions) to be related to this question but I want to do this without building my own version.

My use case:
I am working with Joint Probability Distributions and I am trying to represent each variable on an axis so that computations on it (marginalize, reduce) is a single line operation. For example for a marginalize operation I can simply do a sum over the axis of that variable. For multiplication I can simply do a simple numpy multiplication (after checking if the axes are the same).

Is there a possible workaround this?

Comment: The workaround depends on the use-case I suppose. Care to give more background information?

Comment: You are aware that a 32-dim array, even if it only has a minimal shape of [2]*32 and float32 dtype, would take up 16gb of memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about maintaining the data in a 1d, and selectively reshaping to focus on a given dimension

To illustrate

```
In [252]: x=np.arange(2*3*4*5)
```

With full reshape

```
In [254]: x.reshape(2,3,4,5).sum(2)
Out[254]: 
array([[[ 30,  34,  38,  42,  46],
        [110, 114, 118, 122, 126],
        [190, 194, 198, 202, 206]],

       [[270, 274, 278, 282, 286],
        [350, 354, 358, 362, 366],
        [430, 434, 438, 442, 446]]])
```

With partial reshape - same numbers, different result shape

```
In [255]: x.reshape(6,4,5).sum(1)
Out[255]: 
array([[ 30,  34,  38,  42,  46],
       [110, 114, 118, 122, 126],
       [190, 194, 198, 202, 206],
       [270, 274, 278, 282, 286],
       [350, 354, 358, 362, 366],
       [430, 434, 438, 442, 446]])
```

I'm not going to test this on anything approaching 32+ dimensions.  As was noted in the comment, if many of the dimensions are larger than 1 the overall array size will be excessively large.

Answer (score 4):

**Easy workaround**

If you create a `np.array(np.array(li))`
Where `li` is a `list` and `len(li) > 32`, it'll return an ndarray as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.array` but not `np.ndarray`

Answer (score 0):

As of 11/17/2020, the limit to the number of dimensions for numpy arrays remains 32. To find out I ran the following code:

```py
for dim in range (1, 100):
    arr_n_dim_list = [1]*dim
    arr_n_dim = np.ones((arr_n_dim_list))
    print(arr_n_dim.shape)
```

The last line of the outputs is:

```
ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 33
```