# N dimensional array in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

New at Python and Numpy, trying to create 263-dimensional arrays.
I need so much dimensions for Machine Learning model. 
Of course one way is using numpy.zeros or numpy.ones and writing code as below  :

```
x=np.zeros((1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))   #and more 1,1,1,1
```

Is there an easier way to create arrays with many dimensions?

Comment: `np.zeros([1] * 263)`

Comment: Also note that you run into `ValueError` if your array has more than 32 dimensions.

Comment: By default, [NumPy arrays can have at most 32 dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35192518/190597).

Comment: Do you actually mean a 263-dimensional array? Or a 1-dimensional array of size 263?

Comment: Why do you want that? Most dimensions would have to have size 1, otherwise memory usage would explode. And what good is a dimension of size 1?

Comment: Yes i mean 263 dimensional array

Comment: So in python exist other container without  32-dimensions limit?

Comment: Can you give a little background of why you need 263 dimensions?  It's difficult to recommend anything without a use-case.

Comment: Take a look a this thread : [initialize a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535374/initialize-a-numpy-array)

Comment: re: your edit - "Machine learning" doesn't generally need that many dimensions, and I doubt any ML package could even process anything that high-dimensional.  Please outline your use-case.

Comment: For a quick reference, look at this: http://www.safarnuma.com/2017/09/numpywhy-so-serious.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You don't need 263-dimensions**. If every dimension had only size 2, you'd still have `2 ** 263` elements, which are:
    14821387422376473014217086081112052205218558037201992197050570753012880593911808

You wouldn't be able to do anything with such a matrix : not even initializing on Google servers.

You either need an array with 263 values :

```
>>> np.zeros(263)
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.])
```

or a matrix with 263 vectors of M elements (let's say 3):

```
>>> np.zeros((263, 3))
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       ...
       ...
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

There are many advanced research centers that are perfectly happy with vanilla Numpy. Having to use less than 32 dimensions doesn't seem to bother them much for quantum mechanics or machine learning.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation, your solution fits to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the `numpy` documentation, `help(np.zeros)` gives

```
zeros(shape, dtype=float, order='C')

Return a new array of given shape and type, filled with zeros.

Parameters
----------
shape : int or sequence of ints
    Shape of the new array, e.g., ``(2, 3)`` or ``2``.
...
Returns
-------
out : ndarray
    Array of zeros with the given shape, dtype, and order.
...
```

The shape argument is just a list of the size of each dimension (but you probably knew that).  There are lots of ways to easily create such a list in python, one quick way is

```
 np.zeros(np.ones(263, dtype=int))
```

But, as others have mentioned, `numpy` has a somewhat arbitrary limitation of 32 dimensions. In my experience, you can get similar and more flexible behavior by keeping an index array showing which "dimension" each row belongs to.

Comment: @Stefan, thanks for pointing that out.  I've fixed it by passing in the `int` datatype explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, for ML applications you don't actually want this:

```
shape = np.random.randint(1,10,(263,))
arr = np.zeros(shape)  # causes a ValueError anyway
```

You actually want something sparse

```
for i, value in enumerate(nonzero_values):
    arr[idx[i]] = value
```

`idx` in this case is a `(num_samples, 263)` array and `nonzero_values` is a `(num_samples,)` array.

ML algorithms usually work on these `idx` and `value` arrays (usually called `X` and `Y`) since the actual arrays would be enormous otherwise.

Sometimes you need a "one-hot" array of your dimensions, which will make `idx.shape == (num_samples, shape.sum())`, with `idx` containting only 0 or 1 values.  But that's still smaller than any sort of high-dimetnsional array.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new package called DimPy which can create multi-dimensional arrays in python very easily. To install use
 `pip install dimpy`
Use example

```
from dimpy import *
a=dim(4,5,6) # This is a 3 dimensional array of 4x5x6 elements. Use any number of dimensions within '( ) ' separated by comma
print(a)
```

By default every element will be zero. To change it use `dfv(a, 'New value')`
To express it into numpy style array, use
`a=npary(a)`